# How to set description through ORM

Tags: magento-1.9

I have information I imported from eBay but the descriptions are HTML and can't be imported through CSV data flows. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it through Magento ORM.

Comment: I was able to set it using $product->setDescription($desc)… oddly enough it is not displaying in the front end. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Do you see the description in Edit product page under Magento Admin?

Comment: I was able to get it working using $product->save()

Comment: Issue is resolved, right?

Comment: Yes, it's resolved.